# Session crashes when unplugging USB-C hub with HDMI monitor

Tags: gnome, wayland, 21.04, mutter

Ubuntu 21.04, Wayland Session on Gnome 3.38 via Mutter 3.38.4. Dell XPS 13 9300.

I have a USB-C hub which provides power, HID, and HDMI connectivity. Nine times out of ten, when I unplug this dongle, the screen goes black for a while and my user session is reset, presenting me with the login screen. When I log in again, all my open GUI programs have been killed (but background services are still running).

I believe this is due to Mutter (Wayland) crashing, but how can I prevent this?

Sometimes I will see a bunch of `@@@@@@@` symbols on a black terminal screen before the login screen is shown.

In `dmesg`, I find the following:

```
[435887.627817] Call Trace:
[435887.627823]  typec_altmode_update_active+0x60/0x100 [typec]
[435887.627834]  ? cancel_work_sync+0x10/0x20
[435887.627842]  typec_remove+0xee/0x110 [typec]
[435887.627853]  __device_release_driver+0x181/0x240
[435887.627859]  device_release_driver+0x29/0x40
[435887.627864]  bus_remove_device+0xe1/0x150
[435887.627868]  device_del+0x19c/0x3e0
[435887.627873]  ? klist_put+0x23/0x90
[435887.627880]  device_unregister+0x1b/0x60
[435887.627885]  typec_unregister_altmode+0x30/0x40 [typec]
[435887.627896]  ucsi_unregister_altmodes+0x46/0xa0 [typec_ucsi]
[435887.627902]  ucsi_handle_connector_change+0x2d8/0x510 [typec_ucsi]
[435887.627910]  process_one_work+0x220/0x3c0
[435887.627914]  worker_thread+0x50/0x370
[435887.627918]  kthread+0x12f/0x150
[435887.627923]  ? process_one_work+0x3c0/0x3c0
[435887.627926]  ? __kthread_bind_mask+0x70/0x70
[435887.627932]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
[435887.627941] ---[ end trace b6d883829019f6e9 ]---
```

Comment: Did you find anything? I pretty much get the same behaviour with my XPS 17 when I disconnect my USB-C monitor:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375370/session-crash-when-i-disconnect-external-monitor As far as I can tell, I don't even see anything related to the event in dmesg apart from generic USB disconnect messages.

Comment: I did not find anything and it is still happening to me pretty much any time I have an external USB-C monitor plugged in and I unplug it. It doesn't _always_ happen though, but it's pretty cumbersome to pinpoint the exact circumstances.

Comment: It looks like we have a similar issue, the only thing I found related to this problem is this post, but it's kinda old so I doubt the same bug would be present 4 years later:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1733127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot I had left this one unanswered. I've never experienced the issue again after disabling the Ubuntu Dock (which is a shell extension and I learned that these are capable of bringing the whole shell down).

So go to the AppLauncher, and enter "extensions" to open the Extensions panel. Then turn off the Ubuntu dock and learn how to use GNOME without.

Hint: 3-finger trackpad down gets you your applications. Repeat to get to the launcher. Or press the Super key (Windows or otherwise). I don't miss the dock too much :)