# Session crash when I disconnect external monitor

Tags: nvidia, gnome, multiple-monitors, 21.04, thunderbolt

Hardware:

- XPS 17 with Ubuntu 21.04 - Wayland and Nouveau drivers for the RTX 2060
- External monitor plugged with Thunderbolt port

Behaviour:

When I disconnect the external monitor, 25% of the time the screen goes black for 5 seconds and then brings me back to the login screen. After I log in everything is gone and it looks like a brand new session.

I get a crash report with this info in the Title section:

*gnome shell crashed with sigsegv in g_cclosure_marshal_void__objectv()*

Not sure where to find the log for it to attach it here and no clue where to start to resolve this.